# Looking at what comes after potential selection regex

Tags: python, regex

When you want to select some text from HTML using regex and it is of importance what comes after the potential selection I would imagine that you'd have to do something like this:

```
selected = re.findall(r'<a (.*?) >About', text)
```

Obviously this does not work but what is the right way to do this?

Comment: I dont really know what your question is

Comment: I'm sorry it is a little difficult for me to paraphrase the question but I'd like to know how you can make sure that Python also looks at 'About' which comes after the place where the selected text is supposed to be.

Comment: Are you looking for look-ahead assertions? `.*?(?=\s*>About)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a lookahead assertion. [From the python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> (?=...)
> Matches if **...** matches next, but doesn’t consume any of the string. This is called a lookahead assertion. For example, Isaac (?=Asimov) will match 'Isaac ' only if it’s followed by 'Asimov'.

In your case:

```
re.findall(r'<a (.*?)(?= *>About)', text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `re` module if you want to make use of regex in python. `re.findall` is a good method to use for putting all the matching texts into lists.

```
import re
print(re.findall(r'<(\w+)\s+(.*?)\s*>(.*?)</\1>', '<a href="#about">About</a>'))
```

This outputs:

```
[('a', 'href="#about"', 'About')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `re` takes proper care of the prefix and the suffix:

```
a = '<a href="#about">About</a>'
re.findall(r'<a (.*?) >About', a)
[]
re.findall(r'<a (.*?)>About', a)
['href="#about"']
re.findall(r'<a (.*?)>Abo ut', a)
[]
```